# React conditional render based on user selection without using react router dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have exactly four components that I want to render based on the selection of a user, the user has the following choices: -

Home
About
Work
Contact

I am wanting this all to be on the default route, the component that renders the icons is a Burger Menu, all of the above uses styled-components and hooks, I am trying to implement it with using CSS display: none.

If I was to continue down the display: flex : Display: none route, I have worked out that there would be 12 false choices and 4 truthy choices: -

| Component | Visible | Boolean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Home | Yes | True |
| Others | No | False |

| Component | Visible | Boolean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| About | Yes | True |
| Others | No | False |

| Component | Visible | Boolean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Work | Yes | True |
| Others | No | False |

| Component | Visible | Boolean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Contact | Yes | True |
| Others | No | False |

Code examples below: -

```
const Home: React.FunctionComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isClicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(true);

    return (
        <HomeContainer>
            <LeftContainer>
                <h1>NS</h1>
                <SocialLinks fill={'black'} />
            </LeftContainer>
            <RightContainer>
                <Header>
                    <BurgerMenu isOpen={isOpen} setOpen={setOpen} />
                    <Menu
                        isOpen={isOpen}
                        isClicked={isClicked}
                        setClicked={setClicked}
                        setVisible={setVisible}
                    />
                </Header>
                {isClicked && (
                    <TechnicalKnowledge
                        isVisible={!isClicked}
                        isHidden={!isClicked}
                    />
                )}
                {isClicked && (
                    <ContactForm isVisible={!isVisible} isHidden={!isClicked} />
                )}
            </RightContainer>
        </HomeContainer>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Styled Component Example from TechnicalKnowledge:

```
const TechnicalKnowledgeContainer = styled.div<{
    isHidden?: any;
    isVisible: any;
}>`
    display: ${({ isHidden }) => (isHidden ? 'flex' : 'none')};
    display: ${({ isVisible }) => (isVisible ? 'none' : 'flex')};
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    h3 {
        padding-top: 1rem;
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }
    margin: 20% 20% 0% 0%;
`;
```

I am also wondering if there could be another approach, as I was thinking would it be easier to implement a switch statement to handle each scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I use to mix useState with useEffect to load something depending on user choices like this:

```
const [choiche, setChoice] = useState(default);
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect( () => {
  setOptions(conditionalOptions) 
}, [choice]);
```

This way those components using options hook will be updated at the same time with choice hook

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to just store a `boolean` state.  You need to know *which* of the four sub-pages is currently selected.  You can easily derive an `isVisible` value for each sub-page based by comparing if it matches the page name stored in the state.

```
const [tab, setTab] = useState("Home");
```

You can conditionally render based on whether the component matches the state.

```
{tab === "Home" && <Home/>}
{tab === "About" && <About/>}
{tab === "Work" && <Work/>}
{tab === "Contact" && <Contact/>}
```

Yes you can also do that in a `switch`.

```
const renderTab = () => {
  switch (tab) {
    case "Home":
      return <Home/>
...
```

You can also have an object that maps labels to their components.  You would store the component `Home` rather than the instance `<Home />` and only call the component that matches.

```
const components = {
  Home: Home,
...
}

const CurrentComponent = components[tab];
```

```
<CurrentComponent/>
```

I'm not entirely understanding your post and what you mean by the 12 choices.  But I would advise against `display: none`.  I would use conditional rendering in React instead.

I'm also not quite understanding where we are clicking to activate a different page.  It sounds like perhaps you want a nested route?  You can have all traffic to `/page` go to a certain page and then on that page you can control the content that is shown based on the URL like `/page/home`, `/page/contact`, etc. with an additional `Switch` block.